# Open a pdf file locally performance

Tags: javascript, android

I've created a hybrid app which open a pdf file locally using pdf.js
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/. The software works well but it takes 5-10 seconds to open the file. Why it is so slow and how to make it run faster?
i've tested it on Android simulator.

thank you

Comment: Does it fare any better on a real device?

Comment: have not tested since it is in worklight

Comment: Why not test it on a real device since it is in worklight? The slow rendering might be owing to the simulator.

Comment: I have tested on a real device, yet it is slow like emulator. the pdf is opening in the app offline.